# Where do I get this graph in HTML5

Tags: html, canvas, graph

I would like to know the name of the plugin used in [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Profile/pure%20deal) to create the graph. I cannot find any other similar graphs that have the same CSS effect that is used in this one. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Google has a [Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/).

Answer (score 0):

Its done using Canvas, in HTML5. That graph is also Microsoft (Proprietary) code.

Answer (score 0):

Try Highcharts JS: http://highcharts.com it's a JavaScript library with lots of different graphing capabilities, but requires jQuery though and isn't free.